# Ionic SQLite plugin always throws an exception when deleting

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native, cordova-sqlite-storage

I have an SQLite database, testing on my Android device, with a simple table, where whenever I execute a delete, it always throws an exception, even though the delete succeeds. I can tell it has succeed as the data is gone from the database.

My SQL looks like the following:

```
    let db = await this.sqlite.create({name: 'mydb.sqlite', location: 'default'});
    let delSql = `DELETE FROM ${this.TABLE_NAME} WHERE GroupName = '${groupName}' AND Id IN  ('CAR01','CAR02');
    await db.executeSql(delSql);
```

Catching the exception, it will always throw:

[image]

I have tried to follow the source for the plugin it wraps [here](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/blob/storage-master/src/android/io/sqlc/SQLiteAndroidDatabase.java), but, as we can see at line 163:

```
try {
        rowsAffected = myStatement.executeUpdateDelete();
        // Indicate valid results:
        needRawQuery = false;
```

`rowsAffected` seems to be set if no exception is thrown, yet in my case (as in the screenshot) this comes back as `9`, yet I still get an exception.

Why do I always get an exception?